# Bad allocation with list<shared_ptr>

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, bad-alloc

I have this virtual method:

```
const string& my_class::to_string() const
{
    string str(this->name + string(" "));

    if(!this->children.empty())
    {
        for(const std::shared_ptr<base_class> e : this->children)
            str.append(e.get()->to_string());
    }

    return str;
}
```

Where `children` is a `std::list<std::shared_ptr<base_class>>`, and `my_class` inherits `base_class`. But, after the first recursive call (of `my_class::to_string`), and after I return this child `str`, i get a bad allocation.

Why?

Comment: Why do you do e.get()->to_string() instead of e->to_string() ?

Comment: Well you are returning a reference to a local variable for starters.

Comment: Change return type to `string`, from `const string&` as returning a reference to a local variable (as already pointed out by @BoBTFish).

Comment: @BoBTFish right, write your answer

Comment: There's no need to check whether a container is empty before iterating over it.

Comment: @hmjd why not `const string` as return type?

Comment: @Nick: Why not write `for(auto & e : this->children)`?

Comment: @MikeSeymour yes, but in the real code if it is not empty before call the recursive function i append something to str.

Comment: @Nick, if the caller wants to make it `const` just store it in a `const string`.

Comment: @hmjd good observation, thanks!

Comment: I suppose there is a slight argument for returning `const std::string`, in that if someone inadvertently tries to assign to it, (instead of say compare or assign it to something else) it'll get caught by the compiler. And if the caller wants to store it `const`, it's legal to bind a temporary to a const reference anyway, saves a copy.

Comment: @BoBTFish Doing that makes moving impossible, which is IMO a much stronger con than the pro you gave. Don't do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed by BoBTFish, you should change the function signature to:

```
string my_class::to_string() const
```

since you are modifying the string locally, and not just returning a reference to a class member. Otherwise you simply return a reference to a local string, which is UB.

Answer (score 2):

You return reference to a local variable. This variable become outdated when function to_string() exits its scope. If you use C++11, you can freely return str by value. The move semantics will be used and no copy will happens.

```
std::string my_class::to_string() const
{
}
```